# Java assertion error does not throw error

Tags: java, eclipse, assert

Why doesn't my assert statement yield any result?
I think the first assert statement should fail, but I don't see anything being displayed on Eclipse.

I'm using Eclipse to run this program.

```
package java.first;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "test1";
    assert (s == "test");
    s = "test";
    assert (s == "test");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to set the `-ea` (Enable Assertions) in your JVM options.

---

Unrelated, but you almost always want `string1.equals(string2)` rather than `==`.

Comment: to elaborate on that, you can understand the `==` operator like it answers the following question: the reference to this object points to the same reference of this other object? are this 2 guys allocated in the same chunk of memory, which is only true if it exists 1 and only 1 instance of such object in the whole context of you application (singleton). 
In other words an instance of an object is only `==` to itself.
Since you are comparing it to another instance which holds the same value you need to use `equals`method as stated above.

Comment: when you say `(s == "test")` you are actually creating a new instance of String with the value `test`, so asking if that new instance is `==` to `s` is absolutely not `true`unless you use the `String.intern()` method which will ensure that all strings having same values share same memory.

There is actually much more to know about objects equality, reason why I would recommend giving effective java (2nd edition, Chapter 3, item 8) a chance.

Answer (score 13):

You have to enable assertions with the `-ea` argument (short for `-enableassertions`).

In Eclipse:

- Right-click on the project, then *"Run As"* → *"Run Configurations..."*
- Select the *"Arguments"* tab
- Put `-ea` in the *"VM arguments"* field.
- Select *"Apply"*

Now, running should cause an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 5):

By default, Java disables assertions.  They must be enabled for them to work, [with the -ea option when running your program.](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-enable-assertions.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn assertion checking on at runtime. The Oracle documentation for Java states:

> To enable assertions at various granularities, use the
>   -enableassertions, or -ea, switch. To disable assertions at various granularities, use the -disableassertions, or -da, switch.

Full details on the Oracle website at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable

To change the run-time options for programs run inside Eclipse you will need to modify the parameters Eclipse runs your program with. How to do this will vary depending on your version of Eclipse, but here's how it works in Eclipse Europa...

- Open the Run Dialog (this should be an option under the "Run" menu).
- Click on the tab, "(x)= Arguments."
- In the field for "VM arguments," enter -ea to enable assertions.
- Click on the "Apply" button.

Answer "borrowed" from http://www.coderanch.com/t/416987/vc/enable-Assertions-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable it by using -ea argument.